# ¿Cómo cambiar las imágenes al recargar la página?

Tags: php, javascript, html, imagen

Tengo una página web en la cual en el *index* hay una tabla en la que aparece una foto.

Lo que deseo es que esa foto, cada vez que alguien ingrese, o recargue la página, cambie aleatoriamente.

Las imágenes son 14, estan en la ruta **imagenes/fotohome/......fotohome1,2,3,4,5,..14...jpg**.

En el `body` de la página tengo puesto esto:

```
<td align="center" width="356">
    <?php // Genera un numero aleatorio del 1 al 14
        srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
        $val = rand(1, 14);
    ?>
    <img src="imagenes/fotohome9.jpg" alt="" height="224" width="354">
</td>
```

Ahora puse **fotohome9.jpg** para que aparezca algo allí, pero precisamente lo que quiero es que cambie cada vez que alguien carga la pagina `index`.

Obviamente tengo que poner algo en `head`, pero no sé cómo definirlo.

Encontré algo asi:

```
<link id="gallery" rel="alternate" href="photos.rss" type="application/rss+xml">
<link rel="alternate" href="photos.rss" type="application/rss+xml" title="" id="gallery" />
<link rel = "alternate" type = "application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href = "http://mi_página.com/">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código que tienes debería funcionar. Sólo te falta asignar el número aleatorio al nombre de la imagen:

```
<img src="imagenes/fotohome<?=$val?>.jpg" ...
```

Y debería crear uno nuevo cada vez que recargues. Cuidado con los nombres de 2 cifras.

Comment: Por cierto @Daniel V., no necesitas el `srand` si no quieres que la imagen se repita.

Comment: @DanielV. recuerda qué si la respuesta resolvió sus problemas ,debería  marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: De nada, un placer ayudar.